# ffmpeg - create x thumbs from a video (Windows)

Tags: windows, video, command-line, ffmpeg

I'm looking for an solution to create 16 thumbs from a video.
All solutions I found before, make thumbs from the first frames - but I need the 16 thumbs from the whole video. The video length is different to each video. Some are 3 min, 5 min or 10 min.

If possible, I prefer an solution that works on Windows, because the videos all on my local PC and too big to copy them to my server just for create thumbs.

Could someone help?

Regards
Torsten

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of searching, I found a solution:

```
#/bin/sh
duration=`ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 $1`
ffmpeg -i $1 -vf fps=$2/$duration $1-%02d.jpg
```

Where $1 is the input.file and $2 is the amount of images I want to extract.